# Jx capture not saving files to dekstop

Tags: java

Hello everyone im trying to make video recording software using Jx capture library its supposed to save the file as Desktop.wmv , but after the programm is executed i cant find the file anywhere. The program is running without any errors , but i cant find the file anywhere.   Can someone please help ? Thanks!!

```
package webcrawler;

import com.teamdev.jxcapture.Codec;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.EncodingParameters;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.InterpolationMode;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.VideoCapture;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.audio.AudioCodec;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.audio.AudioEncodingParameters;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.audio.AudioSource;
import com.teamdev.jxcapture.video.VideoFormat;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;


public class WebCrawler {


    static boolean useAudio = true;
    static boolean usePause = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EncodingParameters encodingParameters = new EncodingParameters(new File("Desktop.wmv"));
        encodingParameters.setBitrate(1500000);
        encodingParameters.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        encodingParameters.setInterpolationMode(InterpolationMode.HighQuality);

        VideoCapture videoCapture = VideoCapture.create(VideoFormat.WMV);

        List<Codec> codecs = videoCapture.getVideoCodecs();
        System.out.println("Available video codecs:");
        for (Codec
                codec : codecs) {
            System.out.println("Video codec: " + codec);
        }
        Codec preferredCodec = codecs.get(1);
        System.out.println("Selected video codec = " + preferredCodec);

        encodingParameters.setCodec(preferredCodec);

        if (useAudio) {
            System.out.println("Available audio recording sources:");
            List<AudioSource> audioSources = AudioSource.getAvailable();
            for (AudioSource audioSource : audioSources) {
                System.out.println("audioSource = " + audioSource);
            }
            if (audioSources.isEmpty()) {
                System.err.println("No audio sources available");
            } else {
                AudioSource audioSource = audioSources.get(0);
                System.out.println("Selected audio source = " + audioSource);
                videoCapture.setAudioSource(audioSource);

                List<AudioCodec> audioCodecs = videoCapture.getAudioCodecs();
                if (audioSources.isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.println("No audio codecs available");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Available audio codecs:");
                    for (AudioCodec audioCodec : audioCodecs) {
                        System.out.println("audioCodec = " + audioCodec);
                    }

                    // Enable and configure audio encoding
                    AudioEncodingParameters audioEncoding = new AudioEncodingParameters();

                    AudioCodec audioCodec = audioCodecs.get(0);
                    System.out.println("Selected audio codec = " + audioCodec);
                    audioEncoding.setCodec(audioCodec);

                    encodingParameters.setAudioEncoding(audioEncoding);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("encodingParameters = " + encodingParameters);

        videoCapture.start(encodingParameters);
        if (usePause) {
            System.out.println("Recording started. Press 'Enter' to pause.");
            System.in.read();
            videoCapture.pause();
            System.out.println("Recording started. Press 'Enter' to resume.");
            System.in.read();
            videoCapture.start();
        }
        System.out.println("Recording started. Press 'Enter' to stop.");
        System.in.read();
        videoCapture.stop();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the captured video file located in the current directory of the running application. If you need to put the file to any other location, you have to specify an absolute path to it. For example:

new EncodingParameters(new File("D:\User\Desktop.wmv"));